# Orthonormal basis for the orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

*U* $\subseteq$ $\mathbb R$$^5$ with *span*(*v$_1$*, *v$_2$*) and 
*v$_1$*=  $\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    2 \\
    0 \\
    2 \\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$
 and *v$_2$*=  $\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
    1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

Now I want to find an orthonormal basis for *U$^{\bot}$*.

The following is the "theoretical part", please verify that my thoughts on that are right.

Because $\mathbb R$$^5$ = *U* $\oplus$ *U$^{\bot}$* the dimension of *U$^{\bot}$* = 3.

I need the *vectors* *b$_1$*, *b$_2$* and *b$_3$* in the *span* of *U$^{\bot}$* and all of them need to fulfill that $\langle$*v$_1$*,*b$_i$*$\rangle$ = $0$ and $\langle$*v$_2$*, *b$_i$*$\rangle$ = $0$ (and of course they are linear independent).

After I find my 3 vectors *b$_i$* I need to set them all to $\Vert$*b$_i$*$\Vert$ = 1 with *$\hat b_i$* = *b$_i$* * 1/$\Vert$*b$_i$*$\Vert$.
Now *$\hat b_1$*,*$\hat b_2$* and *$\hat b_3$* is the orthonormal basis of *U$^{\bot}$*.

My problem is I don't know how to work with this "theoretical part" to find those *b$_1$*, *b$_2$* and *b$_3$*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inspection we can easily choose

- $b_1=(1,0,0,0,-1)$
- $b_2=(0,1,0,-1,0)$
- $b_3=(2,-1,-1,0,0)$

such that $b_i\cdot v_j=0$ then we can orthonormalize them by GS process.

Otherwise we can use the vectors $e_i$ for the standard basis together with $v_1$ and $v_2$ as row vectors and obtain a basis by the RREF. Then we can orthonormalize that basis by GS process.

Comment: Do I need _b$_i$_*_b$_j$_ = 0 ( i!=j) ?

Comment: @IPiiro We have for free that $b_1\cdot b_2=0$ but we need to orthonormalize by GS process starting from $b_1$ and $b_2$. Are you aware about that?

Comment: @IPiiro Refer also to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2604493/505767

Comment: I am doing it right now, I need a moment

Comment: @IPiiro Do not hesitate to ask for any clarification, if you show your full work in your OP I can check it. Bye

Comment: With that I got _b$_1$_ = (1/sqrt(2))*( 1 0 0 0 -1),  _b$_2$_ = (1/sqrt(2))*( 0 1 0 -1 0) and _b$_3$_ = (1/sqrt((7/2)))*(1 -0.5 -1 -0.5 1). Can that be right ?

Comment: @IPiiro Yes it seems ok. Recall that you can check directly by dot product.

Comment: Is there any "algorithm" that I need to follow when its not that clear what _b$_i$_ (in the beginning) are ? 
In that example its pretty easy to see what they are but in some different and more difficult situations maybe not.

Comment: @IPiiro In general we need to complete a basis for $R^n$ and then normalize that.

Comment: @IPiiro In any case, by inspection, it is always possible to find some vector orthogonal to a given set of 2 or 3 vectors.

Comment: So I could've just taken each 3  _b$_i$_'s that are completing the basis for the $\mathbb R$ and normalize them with the GS process

Comment: @IPiiro Yes of course, it is the standard method.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that